# Pass string list as parameter to console application

Tags: c#, windows, parameters, arguments, console-application

I need to pass a list of strings as parameter to a console application (developed with C#). 
The console application is started with System.Diagnostics.Process.Start like:

```
string fname = "testDoc";
List<string> myList;  //initialized elsewhere

Process console = Process.Start("Client.exe", "-filename:"+fname+ " -list:"+myList);
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Just out of curiosity. How much data (byte length) is in your list?

Comment: The list contains documents titles in the form: "GUID_fileName.pdf". About the byte length I do not know, I should look at this, since the titles will be different one to the other.

Comment: I have asked because there is a definite limit on command line arguments length

Comment: @Steve: the limit is around 8100 characters, meaning around 200 GUIDs/document titles. In my case this limit is acceptable, therefore I am planning to pass them all within arguments. But thanks for the note!

Comment: All right then, I still believe, barring other solutions like WCF, that's is better to write all that in a file. Ultimately you have a max command line limit of 8191 char (supposing >= winXP)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running

```
Process console = Process.Start("Client.exe", "-filename:" + fname + " -list:" + myList)
```

will execute myList.ToString() and will translate to:

```
Client.exe -filename:testDoc -list:System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]
```

which is not what you want to achieve. Try

```
Process console = Process.Start("Client.exe", "-filename:" + fname + " -list:" + String.Join(",", myList))
```

or something similar.

**UPDATE**

Of course, you might want to consider some more civilized methods of passing data to that process. Common ways include:

- database
- file system (files)
- WCF

**UPDATE**

Given the context supplied in the comment, I'd opt for a completely separate windows service running on the server (non-stop, not invoked) with database used for synchronization:

- database with table `Tasks` with columns `input data`, `output data` and any other you might want (like some dates or user IDs)
- webpage inserting rows into that table as data-to-be-processed appears
- windows service repeatedly (every x seconds) querying the table for unprocessed tasks and performing the tasks if there's any; results get saved in the `output data` column
- on user request webpage queries for a given task and displays it's status, showing the output data if it's there

This is much more robust and scales much better with growing user traffic. The service itself would ideally spawn worker threads for separate tasks to take advantage of multiple cores. With such architecture in place, there's lots of ways to optimize performance and monitor the tasks.

Comment: +1 great hint! - The console application would be started from a web application. The separate process will receive the documents names and will retrieve them invoking a Web Service and merge them into a unique file. From the web application a PrintPage.aspx will poll a folder where the generated file will be dropped. Considering this scenario (where many users can decide to print in the same time) which method would you suggest?

Comment: WCF could be used to get rid of the DB; webpage calls a service via WCF, the service performs work and outputs the result in some way (like a file) so that the webpage has access to it. WCF would enable you to decouple these 2, but all hat would take more work to do right.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you create the list content by

```
String.Join(";", myList);
```

and within your application you rebuilt it with

```
String.Split(";", receivedParameter);
```

Another possibility would be to write the list content into a file and provide as parameter only a filename, that the console application has to read-in.

Answer (score 0):

```
string listValues = String.Join(",", myList.Select(s => String.Format("\"{0}\"", s)).ToArray());
Process console = Process.Start("Client.exe", String.Format("-filename:\"{0}\" -list:{1}", fname, listValues));
```